# Google maps authentication leaks data via url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, privacy, data-protection

I include google maps via script

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&amp;callback=myCallback&amp;libraries=visualization">
</script>
```

Unfortunately it triggers an authentication request that contains the complete current url as parameter.

```
GET /maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fmy.url.com%2F%23%2Fsomething%2Fsomesensitive-data
```

Regarding data protection, this behavior is ***

The data that is not part of the domain is not needed to authenticate the application.

Is there a way to configure the API in a way, that it doesn't send data, that is not necessary for the actual authentication?

Comment: What SDK are you talking about?

Comment: @MrUpsidown google maps

Comment: I call this an API, not a SDK, at least if we're talking about the JS API, which seems to be what you are using. AFAIK, there is no way to change this behavior on the API side. Maybe you can find a solution on your side to somehow remove sensitive data from the URL before the API call. You can also [open a new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) in the tracker if you believe this should be addressed by Google.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Merec no. Google doesn't want to fix it -.- Really stupid: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141975416